# PATHS specified in cmake find_package in config mode never find my config cmake files

Tags: cmake

I've been having a hard time understanding CMake's `find_package` in Config mode. From what I could understand there are a set of paths that are searched starting with a `<prefix>` and `<prefix>` itself can be sourced from a few places.

I have a local installation of the C++ args library in
`$HOME/fun/args`

```
args
├── include
│   └── args.hxx
└── lib
    ├── cmake
    │   └── args
    │       ├── args-config.cmake
    │       └── args-config-version.cmake
    └── pkgconfig
        └── args.pc

5 directories, 4 files
```

I have a project in
`$HOME/fun/myproject`

and I want to use `find_package` to find the local installation of `args`. So I do this in my CMakeLists.txt

```
project(myproj CXX)

set(argsPath "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../args")
find_package(args REQUIRED CONFIG PATHS ${argsPath})
```

The above always fails to find the config files. I'm expecting it to use `${argsPath}` as a `<prefix>` and search for a folder `<prefix>/lib/cmake/args` and find the config files. But it doesn't work. I've also tried setting `${argsPath}` to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` as well as `args_ROOT` and neither of those work.

The only way I can get it to work is by setting `args_DIR` to `${argsPath}/lib/cmake/args`.

What am I not understanding about how `<prefix>` can be specified?

Comment: Compare how the variables are used in `set` and `find_package` and you find out that one of the usages is wrong. Try`message(argsPath=${argsPath})` for one more hint.

Comment: Thanks for the comments but those were just typos in the question itself and are not problems in my CMake file. I have updated the code snippet abovve.

Comment: Have you tried to run `cmake` with additional `--debug-find` option? That way CMake will print locations where it searches the package.